# Entity Framework and using a specific database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

My Database Team created a database called `XMEN`.

I need to use that specific database with my project. I have full admin rights on that database but not on the server (they won't give it to me).

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

When I run my project, I get the error above because I don't have permission to create a database. How can I use entity frameworks to specify which database to use? I want Entity Framework to manage everything else (tables, relationships, etc)

------------- UPDATED 9/17/2020 - 9:12 AM EST

```
public class XmenContext : DbContext
{
    //public XmenContext(DbContextOptions<XmenContext> options)
    //    : base(options)
    //{
    //}
    public XmenContext() : base("XmenDatabase")
    {

    }
```

Now I get an error saying cannot convert from String to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions

I clicked the link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the database name to the connection string in your configuration file.
If you need some help you can view here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings

If you are having trouble add your connection string to the question (without sensitive information) and I will try to help.

Good luck !

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question. I added sensitive information from code and it is the minimal.

Comment: What about the web.config file? What you have inside it?

Comment: Second question, are you using entity framework core of regular entity framework ? Your project is .net core ?

Comment: EntityFramework Core. My project doesn't have a web.config. I am using appsettings.json

Comment: Ok, so you should override the method OnConfiguring, you can see example here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/                        also I would recommend you to go through the docs here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/